Cookies: Couldn't able to extract chrome / edge v20 cookies using AES Decryption in python
Problem: To read the chrome / edge cookies to extract the XSRF-Token and .AspNet.Cookies values of an user in the browser launched from a desktop application and save it in the registry keys
I used the below code and it was working fine for last 2 months and all of sudden a day back, Secret key was able to extract like asusual, but initialisation vector and encrypted password seems to be different than earlier, both the keys seems to be extracting , but faced with the issue :
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
due to the inproper value extraction, please refer to the values after the code.
import os
import win32crypt
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import sqlite3
import json
import winreg as reg

#Extracting the secret key
def get_aes_key():
local_state_path = 'C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Local state' # Update with your path
with open(local_state_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    local_state_data = json.load(f)
    encrypted_key = local_state_data['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']
    print(encrypted_key)
    encrypted_key_base64_dpapi = base64.b64decode(encrypted_key)
    print(encrypted_key_base64_dpapi)
    encrypted_key_base64 = encrypted_key_base64_dpapi[5:]  # Strip 'DPAPI' prefix
    encrypted_key_base64 = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_key_base64, None, None, None, 0)[1]
    aes_key = encrypted_key_base64  # Strip DPAPI prefix
    return aes_key

def decrypt_payload(cipher, payload):
return cipher.decrypt(payload)

def generate_cipher(aes_key, iv):
return AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)

# Function to decrypt cookie value using AES
def decrypt_aes(dec_aes_key, encrypted_data):
try:
    # (3-a) Initialisation vector for AES decryption
    initialisation_vector = encrypted_data[3:15]
    # (3-b) Get encrypted password by removing suffix bytes (last 16 bits)
    # Encrypted password is 192 bits
    encrypted_password = encrypted_data[15:-16]
    # (4) Build the cipher to decrypt the ciphertext
    cipher = generate_cipher(dec_aes_key, initialisation_vector)
    decrypted_pass = decrypt_payload(cipher, encrypted_password)
    decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass.decode()
    return decrypted_pass
except Exception as e:
    print("%s" % str(e))
    print("[ERR] Unable to decrypt, Chrome version <80 not supported. Please check.")
    return ""

# Path to Chrome's Cookies database
logged_in_user = os.getlogin()
cookies_db = 'C:/Users/' + logged_in_user + '/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User 
Data/Default/Network/Cookies'

# Connect to the Cookies database
conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)
cursor = conn.cursor()

aes_key = get_aes_key()
print(aes_key)

# Example query to fetch cookies
cursor.execute('SELECT host_key, name, encrypted_value FROM cookies')


def set_environment_variable(name, value):
try:
    # Open the registry key for environment variables
    with reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment', 0, reg.KEY_SET_VALUE) as key:
        # Set the environment variable
        reg.SetValueEx(key, name, 0, reg.REG_SZ, value)
    print(f'Successfully set {name} to {value}')
except PermissionError:
    print("Permission denied. You need to run this script with administrative privileges.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Failed to set environment variable: {e}')


for row in cursor.fetchall():
host_key, name, encrypted_value = row
if host_key == "adregression02":
    #print(f'Name: {name}, encrypted value: {encrypted_value}')
    decrypted_value = decrypt_aes(aes_key, encrypted_value)
    #print(f'Name: {name}, Decrypted Value: {decrypted_value.decode("utf-8")}')
    print("Name: %s\ncookie: %s\n" % (name, decrypted_value))
    set_environment_variable(name, decrypted_value)

conn.close()

I think the issue is with the lines below :
def decrypt_aes(dec_aes_key, encrypted_data):
try:
    # (3-a) Initialisation vector for AES decryption
    initialisation_vector = encrypted_data[3:15]
    # Encrypted password is 192 bits
    encrypted_password = encrypted_data[15:-16]
    # (4) Build the cipher to decrypt the ciphertext
    cipher = generate_cipher(dec_aes_key, initialisation_vector)
    decrypted_pass = decrypt_payload(cipher, encrypted_password)
    decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass.decode()
    return decrypted_pass

Below are the values that's extracted :
Name: XSRF-TOKEN, encrypted value: b"v20>QT\xc3.A^E\x85\xc6c+\xac\x0eT\xa3z\xe4\x94\xaa!\x83\x99?\x1e\x04\xdd\x1ad\xbc\x15\r\xf7\x18\x86-\x0bVi\xae\xe8\x0b\x12\x16\xf9+\xb5\xcb\xf8I\x8d\xa9\x1ez\x13\x1fwt\xa5\xb2\x8e\x1dW\xfd\xa1\x99;\xe1\xdc\x8cw[\x05\xd72z\xbfHNm\x05\xcb\x02\xc1\xf5\r\xdd\x9d\xfe\x80\r\x9a:\x81\xcc\x88\xd7-uj\xfe\x9c\xe1\x19\xeb\xbb?@ \x17\xa2\xd1\x87\xc6\xba\x8b\r'\xf1n\r\x1e\x0bK\xad-\xa3r\x1c4d\x93\x14\x9ae\xbca\xfc\xce%\xedc\xf6\x0b/R\xe1\xa1\xe8\xb9\x02_Y\x01\xcd\xe4\xd1\x90@"`
**initialisation_vector--** b'>QT\xc3.A^E\x85\xc6c+'
**encrypted_password--** b"\xac\x0eT\xa3z\xe4\x94\xaa!\x83\x99?\x1e\x04\xdd\x1ad\xbc\x15\r\xf7\x18\x86-\x0bVi\xae\xe8\x0b\x12\x16\xf9+\xb5\xcb\xf8I\x8d\xa9\x1ez\x13\x1fwt\xa5\xb2\x8e\x1dW\xfd\xa1\x99;\xe1\xdc\x8cw[\x05\xd72z\xbfHNm\x05\xcb\x02\xc1\xf5\r\xdd\x9d\xfe\x80\r\x9a:\x81\xcc\x88\xd7-uj\xfe\x9c\xe1\x19\xeb\xbb?@ \x17\xa2\xd1\x87\xc6\xba\x8b\r'\xf1n\r\x1e\x0bK\xad-\xa3r\x1c4d\x93\x14\x9ae\xbca\xfc\xce%\xedc\xf6\x0b/R\xe1\xa1\xe8\xb9\x02_Y\x01\xcd\xe4\xd1\x90@"`
Expected xsrf-token : v3eMK3iMPhdF8tumLxbjEHmSVqwT__4MFAhhFZH6-lP4ffXhfPvACW8oQYuxpQ8OZnI0y8-sVjwc4TobVGDjNTXFlrFI287t5B_SNah9yQSHVkppuRsT510cJXGT05IU9rlJibfMnu-iU4CRk--XyrZ7iOJSugxlKFukH8hDyJ--Gv_F6AUqIo6bFJ1i-10cu7bkZ4hLEvfhdk2q08tKyTn7e6oDfQ6nLicSoKIWjuPvEutpZIZQyK4li32GPirk_ysUKolUbLrl2AjwPVFrCZbgil8yHKyNrmAveY1b0lNNzsDljzsfF_TMLZazpYbbIvEarQuPe6wkL8sQuT-L9YpitNpeW8Wvfgyj96EWCbQ
Can someone please point out what's am missing? or the edge/chrome updated their encryption ?
Right now the encryption update seems to be start with V20 in which the cookie encryption standard has been updated from V10 to V20 since chrome version 127.
I referred the links : https://ohyicong.medium.com/how-to-hack-chrome-password-with-python-1bedc167be3d

Please be more specific than "isn't happening".

@Gaberocksall I have updated the question, let me know if any more details is required, will add it to the question.

On surfing, In reference to the link https://security.googleblog.com/2024/07/improving-security-of-chrome-cookies-on.html , I believe this is due to App-bound encryption update from chrome and edge, is there new way to implement the same solution by decrypting the app bound encryption.

TL;DR: In this Github repository by runassu you can find a description of how to decrypt Chrome v20 cookies, including a Python script.

Chrome:
The main difference to the decryption of v10 cookies is the determination of the AES key for decrypting the cookies. For v10 cookies, the encrypted key (referred to as encrypted_key in the Local State JSON file) only had to be decrypted with DPAPI. For v20, a three-stage decryption of the encrypted key (referred to as app_bound_encrypted_key in the Local State JSON file) is required: First, a DPAPI decryption must be performed using the system account, then a DPAPI decryption using the user account and finally an AES-GCM decryption.
The first two decryption steps, i.e. the DPAPI decryption with the system account and then with the user account, can be implemented as follows (this is essentially the solution from the script above which requires the dependencies pywin32 and pypsexec; pywin allows access to the Win32 API, pypsexec allows the execution of a command via PAExec/PSExec (see e.g. here) using different accounts, as required here):
from pypsexec.client import Client
import os
import sys
import json
import base64

local_state_path = r'%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State'
local_state_path = os.path.expandvars(local_state_path)
with open(local_state_path, "r") as f:
    local_state = json.load(f)

app_bound_encrypted_key_b64 = local_state["os_crypt"]["app_bound_encrypted_key"]
app_bound_encrypted_key = base64.b64decode(app_bound_encrypted_key_b64)[4:] # Base64 decode and remove APPB prefix

arguments = "-c \"" + """from win32 import win32crypt
import base64
encrypted_key = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(base64.b64decode('{}'), None, None, None, 0)
print(base64.b64encode(encrypted_key[1]).decode())
""".replace("\n", ";") + "\""

c = Client("localhost")
c.connect()
try:
    c.create_service()
    # DPAPI decryption with SYSTEM account
    decryption_sys_b64, stderr, rc = c.run_executable(
        sys.executable,
        arguments=arguments.format(base64.b64encode(app_bound_encrypted_key).decode().strip()),
        use_system_account=True
    )
    # DPAPI decryption with User account
    decryption_usr_b64, stderr, rc = c.run_executable(
        sys.executable,
        arguments=arguments.format(decryption_sys_b64.decode().strip()),
        use_system_account=False
    )
finally:
    c.remove_service()
    c.disconnect()

encrypted_content_key = base64.b64decode(decryption_usr_b64)[-60:] # Base64 decode; the last 60 bytes are the encrypted content key

encrypted_content_key contains the content key encrypted with AES-GCM. It is given by the last 60 bytes of the decrypted data (the preceding data essentially contains the Chrome installation path). In the next step, this key must be decrypted using AES-GCM.
encrypted_content_key has the format nonce|ciphertext|tag, whereby the nonce is 12 bytes in size, the ciphertext 32 bytes and the tag 16 bytes, i.e. 60 bytes in total. The AES key required for this encryption is hard-coded in elevation_service.exe (referred to below as elevation_key). A possible imlementation with PyCryptodome is:
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def decrypt_aes_gcm(encrypted_data, key):
    nonce = encrypted_data[0:12]
    ciphertext = encrypted_data[12:-16]
    tag = encrypted_data[-16:]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
    return cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)

elevation_key = base64.b64decode("sxxuJBrIRnKNqcH6xJNmUc/7lE0UOrgWJ2vMbaAoR4c=") # hard-coded key from elevation_service.exe
content_key = decrypt_aes_gcm(encrypted_content_key, elevation_key)

content_key is now the content key with which the cookies can be decrypted with AES-GCM. From here on, decryption is analogous to that of v10 cookies. The cookie data starts at index position 32 (the first 32 bytes are the SHA256 hash of the host_key field, see here):
encrypted_cookie = bytes.fromhex('763230...')
encrypted_cookie_prefix_removed = encrypted_cookie[3:]
cookie =  decrypt_aes_gcm(encrypted_cookie_prefix_removed, content_key)
cookie_content = cookie[32:] # decrypted cookie


Edge:
In contrast to Chrome, the decryption of the encrypted key in Edge is only two-stage and consists of the double DPAPI decryption. There is no AES-GCM decryption:
content_key = base64.b64decode(decryption_usr_b64)[-32:] # Base64 decode; the last 32 bytes are the content key

I.e. the last 32 bytes of the double DPAPI decrypted data are directly the content key (again, the preceding data essentially contains the installation path, now for Edge).
Furthermore, the paths for Local State file and Cookies database are different, i.e. %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\... instead of %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\....

Tested with Chrome v131.0.6778.86, Edge v131.0.2903.63 and Python 3.13 on Windows 10 22H2.
